# Do we have a simpler ternary operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, operators

I just saw this syntax in PHP:

```php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

Why don't we have the same in JavaScript?

I am tired of doing:

```js
var name = obj['name'] ? obj['name'] : 'GOD';
```

Comment: P.S  if we already have it, please let me know

Comment: `var name = obj['name'] || 'GOD';`

Comment: You mean conditional operator. A ternary operator by definition takes three operands - that's what the word ternary means. You cannot have a ternary operator simpler than one that takes three operands - because an operator that takes two, such as the ?? shown here, is a binary operator, just like the arithmetic operators and the concat operator in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) is a recent addition to PHP. It was introduced in PHP 7 (released in December 2015), more than 10 years after the feature was [proposed for the first time](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary#references).

In Javascript, the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) operator can be used for this purpose for ages ([since Javascript was created?!](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/jsspec11/valvar.htm#1011953)).

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) explains:

> **Logical OR (`||`)**
>
> `expr1 || expr2`
>
> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.
>   Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns `true` if either operand is `true`; if both are `false`, returns `false`.

Instead of writing

```
var name = obj['name'] ? obj['name'] : 'GOD';
```

you can use the shorter:

```
var name = obj['name'] || 'GOD';
```

The `||` operator can be used several times to create a longer expression that evaluates to the value of the first operand that is not empty:

```
var name = obj['name'] || obj['desc'] || 'GOD';
```

Comment: I am curious: How did you manage to post an answer 30 minutes after the question was closed?

Comment: I don't know. I answered using the mobile app. Now I remember that after I posted the answer the question was loaded again and it was already closed. I thought at that time that it was closed right between my answer was posted and the question was reloaded but now I see that, indeed, the first version of my answer was posted 30 minutes after the question was closed. Maybe there is a glitch in the Matrix. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can do the following:

```
var name = obj['name'] || "GOD"
```

If the first value is false (`null`, `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `""` or `undefined`), then the second value is going to be assigned.